# Replacing string in table without replacing substrings

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to add a numeric ranking to answers of a customer poll like this:

| answer | answer_with_ranking |
| --- | --- |
| never | 1_never |
| sometimes | 2_sometimes |
| often | 3_often |
| very often | 4_very often |

The problem is, that I have lots of answers that might change with different polls, so I'm trying to use kind of a dictionary.

To do this, I found this code on the internet:

```
let BulkReplace = (DataTable as table, FindReplaceTable as table, DataTableColumn as list) =>
    let
        //Convert the FindReplaceTable to a list using the Table.ToRows function
        //so we can reference the list with an index number
        FindReplaceList = Table.ToRows(FindReplaceTable),
        //Count number of rows in the FindReplaceTable to determine
        //how many iterations are needed
        Counter = Table.RowCount(FindReplaceTable),
        //Define a function to iterate over our list 
        //with the Table.ReplaceValue function
        BulkReplaceValues = (DataTableTemp, n) => 
        let 
            //Replace values using nth item in FindReplaceList
            ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(
                DataTableTemp,
                //replace null with empty string in nth item
                if FindReplaceList{n}{0} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{0},
                if FindReplaceList{n}{1} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{1},
                Replacer.ReplaceText,
                DataTableColumn
                )
        in
            //if we are not at the end of the FindReplaceList
            //then iterate through Table.ReplaceValue again
            if n = Counter - 1 
                then ReplaceTable
                else @BulkReplaceValues(ReplaceTable, n + 1),
        //Evaluate the sub-function at the first row
        Output = BulkReplaceValues(DataTable, 0)   
    in
        Output
in
    BulkReplace
```

My problem is, that this code also replaces the substrings, so it works fine for "often" -> "3_often", but it doesn't work for "very often" -> "4_very 3_often" or "very often" -> "very 3_often" (depending on the order of the replacement steps).

If I use the PowerQuery replace function, I can use the checkbox "Match entire cell contents." which fixes this problem. But I don't want to add 50 steps.

Is there a way to add this option in the m script?

Comment: You did not post example of source data, but assuming you are trying to replace the contents of an entire cell, why don't you just merge the "dictionary" into your original data matching for that column, then expand the replaced name?

Comment: Thats a really good question  didn't think about that way. was so focused on replacing the values...